# Call to a member function bindParam() on string

Tags: php, mysql

このエラーの原因が分からないです。
お手数ですが、教えて頂けると助かります。
よろしくお願いします。

##### エラー内容

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bindParam() on string in /home/users/2/lolipop.jp-7084e0fe7e215321/web/study/mysql/login.php:21 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/users/2/lolipop.jp-7084e0fe7e215321/web/study/mysql/login.php on line 21
```

##### ソースコード

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require './library.php';
$err = [];
$email = '';
$pass = '';
$stmt='';
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $pass = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'pass', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if ($email === '' || $pass === '') {
        $err['login'] = 'blank';
    } else {
        $db = connect();
        $stmt = $db->prepare('select id,name,pass from members where email=:email limit 1');
        if (!$stmt) {
            die($db->error);
        }
    }
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $success = $stmt->execute();
    if (!$success) {
        die($db->error);
    }
    $hash = $stmt->fetchColumn(2);
    $stmt->fetch();
    if (password_verify($pass, $hash)) {
    } else {
        $err['login'] = 'failed';
    }
} ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <title>ログインする</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrap">
    <div id="head">
      <h1>ログインする</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <div id="lead">
        <p>メールアドレスとパスワードを記入してログインしてください。</p>
        <p>入会手続きがまだの方はこちらからどうぞ。</p>
        <p>&raquo;<a href="join/">入会手続きをする</a></p>
      </div>
      <form action="" method="post">
        <dl>
          <dt>メールアドレス</dt>
          <dd>
            <input type="text" name="email" size="35" maxlength="255" value="<?php echo h($email); ?>" />
            <?php if (isset($err['login']) && $err['login'] === 'blank') : ?>
              <p class="error">メールアドレスとパスワードを入力して下さい</p>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if (isset($err['login']) && $err['login'] === 'failed') : ?>
              <p class="error">ログインに失敗しました</p>
            <?php endif; ?>
          </dd>
          <dt>パスワード</dt>
          <dd>
            <input type="password" name="password" size="35" maxlength="255" value="<?php echo h($pass); ?>" />
            <?php if ($err['login'] === 'blank') : ?>
              <p class="error">パスワードを入力して下さい</p>
            <?php endif; ?>
          </dd>
          <dt>ログイン情報の記録</dt>
          <dd>
            <input id="save" type="checkbox" name="save" value="on">
            <label for="save">次回からは自動的にログインする</label>
          </dd>
        </dl>
        <div>
          <input type="submit" value="ログインする" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="foot">
      <p><img src="images/txt_copyright.png" width="136" height="15" alt="(C) H2O Space. MYCOM" /></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

エラーメッセージから考えると「$stmtが文字列なのにbindParam()を呼び出そうとしている」となります。
つまり

```
$stmt='';
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$pass = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'pass', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if ($email === '' || $pass === '') {
    $err['login'] = 'blank';
} else {
    $db = connect();
    $stmt = $db->prepare('select id,name,pass from members where email=:email limit 1');
    if (!$stmt) {
        die($db->error);
    }
}
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

先頭で`$stmt='';`と初期化したままの`$stmt`に対して`bindParam()`を呼び出そうとしてエラーになっているのでしょう。
`$email`が空もしくは`$pass`が空なので、データベース接続をせずにif文を抜けているためだと考えられます。ちゃんと`$email`と`$pass`に値が入っているか確認してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。 var_dumpでemailとpassを調べると値は入ってます。

Comment: すみません。括弧がずれていました。